Probability of four cards from one suit and 3 from two other suits
I'm looking for the probability of drawing 10 cards from a deck of 52 and getting 4 cards of one suit and 3 in two other suits. My first thought was that this is $\frac{{13 \choose 4} \times 4 \times {13 \choose 3} \times 3 \times {13 \choose 3} \times 2}{{52\choose 10}}$, because we have 4 options for the first suit, 3 for the second, and 2 for the third. However, instead of $4\times 3 \times 2$ is it instead required to look at the number of ways to take 3 suits from 4 (i.e., ${4\choose 3}$)?

Choosing first spades and then hearts for the $3-$card suits is the same as choosing first hearts then spades.   This is not the same as $\binom 43$ since the $4-$card suit is distinguished.  Rather it's the same as $\binom 32$ since you are choosing $2$ suits from the the left over after you picked the $4-$card suit.

The
$$\frac{\binom{13}{4} \times \binom{13}{3} \times \binom{13}{3}}{\binom{52}{10}}$$
portion of your answer is correct.
The remaining portion might be reasoned as follows:

There are $~4~$ ways of selecting which suit will be the one to provide four cards.

Then, you would surmise that there are $~3~$ ways of picking the next suit, and then $~2~$ ways of picking the third suit.


This creates the auxiliary factors in the numerator of $~4 \times 3 \times 2.$
This approach has a subtle flaw.
Suppose (for example) that you are going to receive $~4~$ spades, $~3~$ hearts, $~3~$ diamonds, and $~0~$ clubs.
You would then count separately, the following two selections:

having the second suit chosen to be hearts and the third suit chosen to be diamonds.

having the second suit chosen to be diamonds and the third suit chosen to be hearts.


It was okay to use this approach when selecting (for example) spades as the first suit, because none of the other three suits will provide exactly four cards.
However, the hearts and diamonds are both providing exactly three cards.  Therefore, the last two bullet points above are equivalent.  This means that you are over-counting by a factor of $~2.~$
What this implies is that specifically because two of the four suits are providing the exact same number of cards, you must have an additional over-counting adjustment factor of
$$\frac{1}{2!}.$$
So, you need to multiply your original computation by $~\dfrac{1}{2!}.$

There are two alternative ways of thinking about the enumeration, that allow you to avoid having to apply an over-counting adjustment factor:

You can reason that there are $~4~$ ways of selecting which suit will provide four cards (e.g. spades), and then $~3~$ ways of selecting which suit will provide zero cards (e.g.) clubs. 
This leads to the auxiliary factors of $~4 \times 3.$

Alternatively, you can reason that there are $~4~$ ways of selecting which suit will provide four cards.  You can then reason that there are $~3~$ suits remaining, and you have to decide which $~2~$ of these suits will provide three cards each.  
The number of ways of doing this is $~\displaystyle \binom{3}{2}.$ 
So, this alternative approach leads to the auxiliary factors of $~4 \times \displaystyle \binom{3}{2}.$


